# AngularJs - Use filter with ng-bind in directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a simple directive like that one :

Directive js :

```
.directive('pageHeader', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            title: '=',
            subtitle : '='
        },
        templateUrl: 'pages/templates/pageHeader.html'
    };
})
```

Directive html :

```
<div class="page-header">
    <span class="header-view-title" ng-bind="title"></span>
    <span class="header-view-subtitle" ng-bind="subtitle"></span>
</div>
```

And i'm using that directive like this way :

```
<page-header title="'The blue elephant'" subtitle="'is walking to the street'"></page-header>
```

There's a way to passa a filter to the 'title' and 'subtitle', and use that filter.
I tried like this, but failed :

```
<page-header title="The blue elephant | myfilter" subtitle="is walking to the street | myfilter"></page-header>
```

Did someone already need do something like that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thy this instead:

```
title="'The blue elephant' | myfilter"
       ^-- note quotes --^
```

Comment: Without quotes Angular thinks that `The blue elephant` is variable, but `$scope['The blue elephant']` is undefined.

Comment: I was trying with quotes around the filter too, like that : title="'The blue elephant | myfilter'", causing probably a undefined object